# How can I get the data of the second web page?

Tags: html, r, web, rvest

I am trying to get the data from a web in R using rvest package: https://etfdb.com/stock/AAPL/

But no matter how I tried, I can only get the table of the first page. Could anybody help me do this? Thank you so much.

See code below. tb1 and tb2 are the same!! That's wired.

```
url1 <- "https://etfdb.com/stock/AAPL/#etfs&sort_name=weighting&sort_order=desc&page=1"
url2 <- "https://etfdb.com/stock/AAPL/#etfs&sort_name=weighting&sort_order=desc&page=2"

tbs1 <- rvest::html_nodes(xml2::read_html(url1), "table")
tbs2 <- rvest::html_nodes(xml2::read_html(url2), "table")
tb1 <- rvest::html_table(tbs1[1])[[1]]
tb2 <- rvest::html_table(tbs2[1])[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website post GET requests to update JSON data to the table. After some attempts, this is the code I came up with to deal with JSON data: (not a beautiful code but it works)

```
library(rjson)
library(rvest)
library(writexl)

lastpage <- 9;
df <- data.frame();
for (i in 1:lastpage){
  x <- fromJSON(file = paste("https://etfdb.com/data_set/?tm=40274&cond={%22by_stock%22:25}&no_null_sort=&count_by_id=true&limit=25&sort=weighting&order=desc&limit=25&offset=", 25 * (i-1), sep = ""));
  x <- x[2][[1]];
  pg_df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), nrow=length(x), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
  df <- rbind(df, pg_df);
}
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$X1[i] <- read_html(df$X1[i]) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE);
  df$X3[i] <- read_html(df$X3[i]) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE);
  df$X5[i] <- read_html(df$X5[i]) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE);
}
df <- data.frame(df$X1, df$X3, df$X5, df$X7, df$X9);
colnames(df) <- c("Ticker", "ETF", "ETFdb.com Category", "Expense Ratio", "Weighting");
write_xlsx(
  df,
  path = "stock.xlsx",
  col_names = TRUE,
  format_headers = TRUE,
  use_zip64 = FALSE
)
```

**Update:**
You can see the data source at the attribute `data-url` of the table here:
[image: data-url]
I'll update the code that makes it easier for you:

```
library(rjson)
library(rvest)
library(writexl)

stock_ticket <- "AAPL";
url <- paste("https://etfdb.com/stock/", stock_ticket, sep = "");
lastpage <- 9;
df <- data.frame();
data_url <- read_html(url) %>% html_node(xpath = "//table[@id='etfs']") %>% html_attr("data-url");
for (i in 1:lastpage){
  x <- fromJSON(file = paste("https://etfdb.com", data_url, "&offset=", 25 * (i-1), sep = ""));
  x <- x[2][[1]];
  pg_df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), nrow=length(x), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
  df <- rbind(df, pg_df);
}
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$X1[i] <- read_html(df$X1[i]) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE);
  df$X3[i] <- read_html(df$X3[i]) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE);
  df$X5[i] <- read_html(df$X5[i]) %>% html_text(trim = TRUE);
}
df <- data.frame(df$X1, df$X3, df$X5, df$X7, df$X9);
colnames(df) <- c("Ticker", "ETF", "ETFdb.com Category", "Expense Ratio", "Weighting");
write_xlsx(
  df,
  path = "stock.xlsx",
  col_names = TRUE,
  format_headers = TRUE,
  use_zip64 = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. If I want to change the ticker, how can I edit it in the link?

Comment: Thanks so much. We can further use this to replace last page. `pages <- read_html(url) %>% html_node("strong.h4") %>% html_text()
pages <- as.integer(as.numeric(gsub(" .*", "", pages)) / 25 + 1)`

Comment: @LarryChen: Might you mark my answer as the solved answer?

Comment: X: Can I ask one more question? Do you know how to increase the speed when I loop through more tickers? It looks like time becomes quite slow after a few tries

Comment: @Larry: My suggestion is to log the system time before and after each block of code to measure the time it takes. Find out which codes take time and try to optimize them.

Comment: But sometimes, there's not much you can improve though.

Comment: About the last page number, I don't know about your code but you might want to consider calculating by the attribute `data-total-row` of the table.